# android studio activity starts before finishing prev one

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

I m calling `prog()` function in the Mainactivity which performs loading page using progress bar and I call just after the prog function  LoginActivity. BUT, it calls login activity before exciting prog function, I am new at the android studio and need your help. here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ProgressBar pb;
int counter = 0;
TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    prog();//loading page
     Intent intentLoginPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
     startActivity(intentLoginPage);

}

public boolean prog(){// to dispay progress bar as loading bar in loading page

    pb = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    final Timer t = new Timer();
    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            counter++;
            textView.setText(counter + "%");//0 to 100%
            pb.setProgress(counter);
            if(counter == 100)
                t.cancel();

        }
    };
    t.schedule(tt,0,60);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: _"it calls login activity before exciting prog function"_ I find that extremly unlikely. However, you're starting some asynchronous work from `prog`.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need call startActivity in run()?:

```
TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            counter++;
            textView.setText(counter + "%");//0 to 100%
            pb.setProgress(counter);
            if(counter == 100) {
                t.cancel();
                Intent intentLoginPage = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentLoginPage);
            }

        }
    };
```